# Other apps can't see PDF printed by Chrome

Tags: chrome-for-android, pdf, printing

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy J3 with Android 7.  Here's what I did to print the PDF from Chrome:

1. Open Google Chrome app and go to a website I want to save
2. Go to : Menu, Share ..., Print.  (It defaults to Save as PDF and shows the preview.)
3. Click the yellow circle to Save PDF.  (It goes to "Save to", showing My Files > Internal Storage)
4. Click into the Download folder.
5. Click "DONE"

Just to be sure, repeat steps 1-4 and see that the file is now in the Download folder.  But now,

6. Open My Files app
7. Click "Downloads".  The file doesn't show up.  Same problem in other apps.

How can I open the printed PDF from other apps?

Comment: Does the app you are using have permissions granted to read? I suppose so, you can try alternate pdf reader app to check if it is an issue with your app

Comment: I think you got two folders there - Download and Downloads.